# How can I use JSON Schema to validate a pipe separated string input from a checkbox array

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have some data that is the result of a user selecting 2 checkboxes and submitting a form. There are 10 different options the user is able to choose from, and the two they do choose from are concatenated into a string and separated using the `|` character, they are then pushed through to a JSON schema file which is used to validate the input.

So to be more clear, if we have the following checkboxes:

```
[] Option A
[x] Option B
[] Option C
[x] Option D
... etc
```

As we can see, option B and option D are checked. Therefore the string that will be pushed through to be validated will be:

```
"Option B|Option D"
```

This is why the validation is difficult. If it was a single value the value could be validated easily by making use of the `enum` keyword provided by JSON schema. For example the below schema could be used:

```
"answer": {
          "enum": [
            "Option A",
            "Option B",
            "Option C",
            "Option D"
          ]
        }
```

However since the incoming value won't be any of those values, and will actually be a concatenation of two values with a separator, this approach will not work as the value will never pass the validation.

Is there any way that I can adjust this schema or use other features of JSON Schema so that the string `"Option B|Option D"` and any other combination will pass validation?

Comment: Why are you putting multiple values into a single string?

Comment: Are you able to change the schema? I would just re-write it to have OptionA : true, OptionB : false, etc. the trade off is a larger object, but that doesn't seem to be a requirement.

Comment: [Bitwise enumerations](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/518) are currently being discussed as a proposed feature.  You may want to read over there for a workaround.

Comment: @melpomene Not something I have control of or the ability to change.

Comment: @TheFastCat Do you mean the input submission? Rather than the schema?

Comment: @Jake12342134 yes